How to upgrade to 24.10
I wanted to know how to upgrade from version 24.04.1 LTS to 24.10. I have Ubuntu Pro, so how do I do it?

Did you read the docs - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OracularUpgrades     You are aware that Pro services only exist for LTS releases, 24.10 being a non-LTS will mean you'll lose Ubuntu Pro additional services

Ubuntu Pro is for LTS only. You can remain enrolled in Ubuntu Pro, but the services (Livepatch, ESM, etc) won't work.

Review the file /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

The last line of the file must read Prompt=normal


Best practice is to uninstall all non-Ubuntu software, and to disable the non-Ubuntu sources that software came from. Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible.

The #1 cause of broken upgrades is non-Ubuntu packages.


A backup of your data at this point is very wise.
Making a 24.10 LiveUSB installer is also wise.

You may not need either. But if something goes wrong, these two tools are enough to reduce most catastrophes to mere inconveniences.


Ensure your system is updated
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Read the output. All Ubuntu-provided packages must be fully-upgraded before proceeding.

If any packages are "held" or "kept back", then the release-upgrade will abort.


When you are on reliable mains power and have a reliable network connection, run:
do-release-upgrade

Check the screen every few minutes. If the system asks you a question, the release-upgrade will pause while awaiting your reply.



Related: Error while trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10: "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."
To enable non-LTS upgrades on GUI:

or on CLI:
sudo sed -i 's/^Prompt=.*/Prompt=normal/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

And the rest, if you are lucky, is just the standard:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade

